# Add cstheory.stackexchange.com to the list of site for "off-topic" questions

Tags: feature-request, off-topic, migration

Somebody recently posted a very theoretical question, and I went to flag it by clicking *Flag* > *It doesn't belong here* > *off-topic*, and I was unable to directly select cstheory.stackexchange.com. The cstheory site is where I felt it best fit, so I had to just flag it as *is off-topic*. I suggest that cstheory.stackexchange.com be added to the list of *off-topic* SE sites.

Comment: I'm for this change (adding more migration paths), but no more than 5 on the primary dialog is fair enough. The suggestion hasn't yet been made, however, to provide perhaps a button or text link "Show more sites..." which can either go to another page of 5 or show all SE sites across the network. That functionality can also be made available only at a certain rep level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, sites aren't allowed to have more than 5 migration paths, and SO is already at the limit. To add cstheory another target would have to be removed, and I think all the current targets are used quite a bit.

Note that mods can migrate posts anywhere, so for cases like this you can flag for mod attention and ask them to migrate to cstheory

Comment: So, flagging as generally off-topic, and just leaving a comment on the question to suggest a move to cstheory would be appropriate?

Comment: @arcain I just flag as "other" and put "Please migrate to cstheory" in the description

Comment: Well, I messed that up ;) Thanks, that's good info.

Comment: what's the question (out of curiosity) ? I'm a cstheory mod

Comment: @suresh - Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes

Comment: ah interesting. it appears to be closely related to these: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?q=regex

Comment: -1: 5 migration paths is a self impose arbitrary limit imposed by the SE software. Any such rule (like +10 for up votes on questions) is subject to revision.

Comment: @Richard That's like somebody asking how much rep you get for an question upvote, another user answering "+5", and you downvoting them because you think it should be +10. Jeff is very against adding more entries to the migration dialog, and no amount of downvoting my correct answer is going to change that

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: First: as a meta down vote does indeed mean I disagree (and if I had disagreed with the change to +5 I would have down voted there). Second: "Jeff has decided no more than five" is pretty much the definition of arbitrary (and I doubt I would have down voted if the A was worded as such, especially if there is a link to down vote more directly).

Comment: @Richard What do you think "sites aren't allowed to have more than 5 migration paths" means? And I know what downvoting on meta means, but disagreeing with my answer means you're saying "sites are allowed to have more than 5 migration paths" -- they're very much not. You disagree with "sites *shouldn't* be allowed to have more than 5 migration paths", but nobody's saying that here; go find a post somewhere else that does say that and downvote that

Answer (score 3):

The flagging dialog supports flagging as "belongs on an unlocked migration path" but indeed, it does not support flagging as "belongs on arbitrary Stack Exchange site".. this is for a reason.

However, if you feel strongly a question belongs on another SE site, feel free to flag as

- it needs ♦ moderator attention
- other
- this should probably be migrated to `arbitrary.stackexchange.com`

Like so:

[image: flag as belongs on arbitrary SE site]

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to follow these steps in the future. This was my first flag, and I thought cstheory would be a relevant addition to the migration dialog, but didn't know that there could only be  five migration suggestions in the dialog.

Comment: The limit of 5 migration paths is pretty annoying. Half my flags are "migrate to xyx.SE"