# More SE sites to migrate to when casting close votes?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

There have been tons of off-topic questions ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5887356/464744), but I'm sure everyone has seen many more) which definitely belong to less-used SE sites, like [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

When you case a close vote, I think it would be nice if under the `Off Topic` section, there were less-used SE sites. If people don't know about the sites, how will they ever get any traffic?

Just a thought.

Comment: See also: [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites).

Comment: The current implementation supports only 5 sites to migrate to by design.  There are discussions about it around here somewhere.  If you feel there's a better place for a question than the existing list, flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of your example, that question should not be migrated to *any* other site in the first place. It's just a bad question, and [the first rule of migration is that you should not migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986).

> Simon is yelling four times louder than a jackhammer. If the jackhammer is measured at 100 decibels, how loud is Simon?

If you absolutely think that a question is of good enough quality to merit migration to a site that is *not* listed in the pop-up, you should flag that question for moderator attention. Explain why and where you think it deserves to be migrated. Moderators have the ability to migrate anywhere within the SE network.

Jeff has said numerous times that [we will not be adding more than 5 locations](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1595/add-a-migration-path-to-pro-web-masters-from-super-user/1704#1704) to the "close" pop-up. Not only is presenting too many choices confusing to the user, but it's quite rare that a good physics question is inadvertently asked on Stack Overflow. The common migration paths are all there already.

Comment: I was just using that as an example, but there have been more valid questions. I wasn't aware that mods could migrate to *all* the sites, so thanks for the info!