# Should dba.stackexchange.com be an option when closing "off-topic" questions

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

When we close a question as "off-topic" we are given a list of stackexchange sites we can send it to.

I've found myself wanting to send [dba related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144130/how-to-determine-if-a-index-is-needed) to http://dba.stackexchange.com.

This should be presented as an option when closing an off-topic question, shouldn't it?

Or should there some way you can select any of the 71 (at last count) stackexchange sites?

Comment: Related: [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77264/156620)

Comment: **YES!** we got tons of really DBA questions on Stackoverflow - would be very very helpful to have this as an optionè

Answer (score 8):

There is a hard limit of 5 sites that can be set up as targets for community-driven migrations and one of those slots is always taken up by Meta. It would be unreasonable to make people choose from all SE sites since most of them would never see a migration from Stack Overflow and we can't expect every user to be familiar with every site out there.

However, moderators have the ability to move questions to any site in the network, so your best bet is to flag the question for moderator attention and explain that you think it belongs on DBA instead.

There may be a reason to review which sites are available up in the dialog. If that's the case, you (or someone else) would need to provide evidence that a new migration path is justified (that is, compile a list of questions that should be or have been migrated) and we could ask moderators for migration stats to other sites and see if there's a path that's used less than one of the new proposed ones.

Comment: Possible methods of solving the "Hard limit of 5" problem were suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites/77277#77277) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites/95986#95986).

Answer (score 4):

Most decisions on SE are backed up by data. So is the choice of 5 sites in the close option. The statistics for migrated questions in the past 30 days shows SU, SF, Programmers.SE & Webmasters.SE in the top 4 positions. Add to that, the meta site for Stack Overflow, you have  options.

You probably see a lot of possible migrations to DBA because you might be familiar with the topic, but in the big picture, it doesn't even make the top 5. If anything, TeX.SE would be next in line.

For what it's worth, I think that the route to MSO can be replaced with something else, since it has only 94 migrations in 3 months, coming in the 10th place.

[image]

Comment: +1 for using evidence, though the route to MSO isn't going to be replaced so really there are only four slots available.