# Off-topic closing - Allow more migration targets

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)
>   [Should dba.stackexchange.com be an option when closing “off-topic” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112345/should-dba-stackexchange-com-be-an-option-when-closing-off-topic-questions)

Oftentimes when I see a question about something completely 100% made for Database Administrators, it seems as though my only option is to Flag the post for moderator attention.

At what point would Database Administrators SE be added to the **off topic** listing of SEs that the question *should* be posted on? (or any other non-main SE for that matter)

The reason it is bothersome is because it seems people try to close DBA-like questions to move to Server Fault, when they really belong on Database Administrators.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113775/migrations-to-dba-appear-arbitrary-and-include-questions-that-are-outside-the-r

Comment: See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112427/160166) in the above linked question. DBA is not even in the top 5. If anything, [tex.se] will be the next to get it. Your experience of seeing a lot of DBA questions comes from your selective reading bias.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites

Comment: In the meantime, flagging for moderator attention works well.

Comment: @yoda thanks for the link.  I see what you are saying, and I guess me having a DBA background/interest guides my reading.  Thank you!  Your comment should be an answer.  It's the right answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree, this is the best right now.  I just wonder what the moderator(s) are thinking seeing these hundreds of "this belongs on DBA" flags. :)  I'm sure they're annoyed at me by now. :D

Comment: The number of "should be on DBA" flags in the queue is a relatively small proportion of the overall moderation effort. That said, migration makes the most sense when the questions are *new, with no accepted answers.* Migrating old posts that have already run their course seems less useful.

Comment: @Shark I've voted to close this question since it is a duplicate of that one. Since I've already answered it in that question, you can upvote it if you like.

Comment: @yoda done!  And thank you.  The upvote is reflected in your other post.  Thanks!