# Off-topic flag doesn't cover enough 'exchanges'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

When flagging a question if you go to `'It doesn't belong here'` and then `'Off Topic'` you're presented with a limited list of 'exchange sites'. This in many cases is appropriate but there's a number of instances where you may wish to flag a question as applicable to another site (such as code review or SharePoint).

Could/should this be expanded?