# Can we add some mention of codereview to the SO FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, code-review-se

The question [Experienced PHP developer, please RATE my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020202/experienced-php-developer-please-rate-my-code) received 4 downvotes - it was 5 until I looked at the FAQ and discovered that there is no mention of [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) anywhere in it.

The OP has a history of asking questions that are acceptable on SO, so far as I can see he has never previously received a downvote for one and he certainly has no other questions with a negative score - suggesting he has at least glanced at the FAQ. He has just lost some of the little rep that he has through what is arguably no fault of his own.

Can we add a mention of CR to the "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" section, with the links to SU, SF etc?

Comment: Note that particular example is *horrible* and would be closed on Code Review as not a real question.  Storing *all* the code in pastebin and linking to it completely destroys the context of the question.  Also, for Code Review, it usually helps if *some* indication of what exactly *better* means (faster, smaller, easier to maintain?  What's the goal here?). But I agree with Code Review being posted in the FAQ.

Comment: @casperOne granted the question was not enormously well asked, but at least on CR people would have said "please improve your question in these ways" rather than immediately voting to close as off topic.

Comment: There's still a problem, the community on SO would *still* have to close as off topic and *does not* have the option to migrate to code review when voting to close.  That said, they'd have to flag the question for moderator attention, and then the moderator would migrate it over (assuming it's a good question, we don't migrate crap).  It might seem that while mention of Code Review in the FAQ is a good thing, it doesn't seem to solve the underlying problem that you see, which is giving users the ability to migrate a question to *any* Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @casperOne Indeed, I have previously looked at this and found a few questions on meta specifically asking "Can we add a migrate to CR option" in the off-topic menu and the answer was always "No". I seem to remember finding an answer by one of the SE staff saying "The platform is designed to give 5 options for this reason", although right now I can't find the question.

Comment: I'd downvote that too.  Before I closed it as not a real question.  I'm assuming he is asking for a code review, not for people to actually **RATE** his code.  Anyhow, you ask people to **RATE** your code, they're going to rate it using the up and down arrows next to your question.  And if you ask PHP developers to rate your code, you're asking for it, IYKWIMAITYD.

Comment: Just a note: The question [made it to Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8330/experienced-php-developer-please-rate-my-code), after all. No sign that the OP bothered to read the FAQ there... I'd say the comments left on the SO question were a bit counterproductive, indirect crap migration is not far from direct crap migration.

Comment: @YannisRizos It's *very* far and there's a *huge* difference.  Direct crap migration is either a) the result of a number of higher rep users making the determination that the question is suitable for another site, or b) a moderator making that distinction on their own (but influenced by a flag, in most cases).  Indirect crap migration, in this case, is an *single* user uneducated in how Stack Exchange works spamming the system (intentionally or not).  I fail to see how those two processes are more similar than they are different.

Comment: @casperOne The processes are similar in that the end result is the same, but I'm not denying that my comment was a bit exaggerating. In any case, `Your question is off topic here, but it might be on topic on our sister site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please read the [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) and familiarize yourself with the site before posting.` is my [pro forma](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) migration comment, and I wished migration comments were a bit more like that.

Comment: Oh look, the [question was closed as Off Topic on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/8330/3973)

Comment: @DaveRandom: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites is the feature request for allowing more migrations to mortal users, http://meta.superuser.com/a/1704/69238 is the source of the "no more than five" idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While [@CasperOne is right that this particular question was horrible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120388/can-we-add-some-mention-of-codereview-to-the-so-faq#comment-318179), and would have been closed on CR, in general I think we could do a better job of directing questioners to the right site.

Can we put the evil title filter to good use?  Why not detect certain keywords or phrases in questions—"rate my code", "refactor", etc—and, if found, post a **suggestion** that this question *might* be better suited for CodeReview.SE

Comment: This is a good idea, some tags could be created/existing tag wikis edited to partially implement this with no change the core software.

Comment: The title filter is kind and gentle, and a fine father.  I am insulted by your attempt at character assassination.  You should be ashamed.