# Add dba.stackexchange to stackoverflow "Off Topic" List

Tags: support, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

To the admins:

Could you please add "dba.stackexchange" to the list of "off topic" sites on stackoverflow?

This question comes about in regards to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182535/cant-create-linked-server-mssql-2005

Comment: You could just flag it, you know.

Comment: Only five sites are permitted in the list, so you'll have to make a strong case that DBA is more necessary than Programmers or Webmasters.

Comment: @mmyers: The Programmers' mods could be wanting to give up their spot :-)

Comment: Thank you mmeyers and won't for the insight.  Bolt - not really.

Comment: @Norla: Why not?