# What happened to "off topic - belongs on programmers"?

Tags: support, migration

I just flagged a question that was off topic, that should really be on `programmers`. It was not listed as a choice.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920881/is-there-any-functional-difference-between-immutable-value-types-and-immutable-r

The options were `serverfault`, `superuser`, `tex` and `dba` but no ability to select programmers anymore, why is this?

Comment: Too many people tried to migrate crap that didn't belong there.

Comment: Flag the question for moderation attention and ask for it to be migrated to ProgSE, I just did.

Comment: WTF! I remember that question! And I suddenly see it here?! 0.o

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[It was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134642/150283), as recent stats showed that Serverfault, SU, Tex and DBA were the 4 most common migration paths. SO -> Programmers also had the highest rejected migration rate (~36% the past 90 days), so I presume that contributed to the decision.

Comment: Have you tried explaining that to someone? "I'm sorry, your question isn't programming related. Try **programmers**.stackexchange.com instead!".

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Tex questions outrank security ones that need to be moved.

Comment: Why not let people choose, with a dropdown? I don't get what the extra control is there for?

Comment: @Xaade: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites