# Consider when closing a question that fits to another stackexchange site to migrate it

Tags: feature-request, migration

I came to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732647/convert-rtf-file-to-pdf-file/16734426 that was closed as not constructive.

The reasoning for closing it are not 100% clear to me, but there is enough discussion about this topic ([Help us make "Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" closures more effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv)).

The way I think about it, the question doesn't fall to the shoping list category since it is not asking for the best way to do what hi wants (RTF->PDF) but any way that conforms to his limitations (open+pure java). Maybe it is not a good fit for stackoverflow, but it looks like a good fit for programmers.stackexchange.

Would it be a good idea when closing a question from one site to migrate it to another if it's a perfect fit for it?

Comment: This is already possible. Your tags are wrong (should be [meta-tag:feature-request] and [meta-tag:migration]) IIRC migration to [programmers.SE] has [been disabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134830/what-happened-to-off-topic-belongs-on-programmers) because it was used as trash dump for [so]

Comment: "but it looks like a good fit for programmers.stackexchange" - no. Not at all in fact. Please read their [faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), this is in no way on-topic over there.

Comment: You mean automatically? This will just cause bad questions to change place. Bad idea. It's possible to migrate manually, either by high rep members or a moderator.

Comment: Changed tags to feature-request and migration. OK I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists in two forms:

- Users with vote-to-close privilege can select from a restricted list of sites when they close as off-topic, if they deem the question a **good** candidate for another Stack Exchange site. At least four (out of five) such votes for the same target site are required for a migration to happen that way.
- Moderators can migrate questions to any site. You can flag a question (use the "other" reason) and ask for the question to be migrated to where you think it's best.

In this specific case, it is not on topic **at all** on Programmers. Please read the target site's FAQ before suggesting a target (whether through comments or flags). In general, you shouldn't suggest a migration unless:

1. You are familiar with the target site and you know the question would be welcome there
2. The question is of good quality overall.

Migrating shopping, list, or "do this for me" type questions around isn't productive. The criteria in the question you link to aren't sufficient to not make it shopping question in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to generate PDF report from RTF file. Does anybody know any
>   free way to do this without using MS Office or OpenOffice ?

This question doesn't fit anywhere on SE. First of all, this excludes using MsOffice or OpenOffice without giving any reason for that.

Second, it is tagged as [java](/questions/tagged/java), which suggest that author wants to achieve that in Java (or possibly any other programming language) but it is not stated clearly.

Third, the OP shows no effort, not only in searching for any solution (via `google java convert rtf pdf`, for example), but also with constructing the questions so that it would be possible to define what does OP want without guessing.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer my question. It only justifies the closing of the question mentioned in the answer, but I didn't ask why the question was closed, I asked something else.