# Dynamic list of affiliated sites when voting to close as off-topic

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)

When voting to close a question, [5 stackexchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites) are displayed. *The reason only 5 are displayed is for aesthetic reasons and not to clutter up the screen.*

However, it would be very useful if the 5 affiliate sites displayed, rather than being a fixed list (as they are currently), were **associated to the content of the question**.

For example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453254/true-or-false-every-non-separable-field-extension-of-a-non-separable-field-is-a) is "clearly" a likely candidate for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) since it is tagged algebra.

Comment: While I agree with this, I doubt it will happen. Questions can be migrated to any site in the network. The five in the list just help us regular users point it somewhere. If you feel strongly the question belongs on a site other than one of those listed, flag for moderator attentino with the "other" option, and explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think overall the concept is good. However, while your case/example is fairly clear, for other cases, something like this would be hard to implement.

Which tags apply to which affiliate sites?

Which tags would be used to determine the affiliate? (making up a tag combination for example, [algebra](/questions/tagged/algebra)+[database](/questions/tagged/database)+[algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm))

Is there a weighting system involved, or is everything taken to be a 1:1 match? I think weighting would be better, but that much more difficult to tackle.