# Will other sites (like cstheory) be suggested when marking post as off-topic?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add cstheory.stackexchange.com to the list of site for “off-topic” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77074/add-cstheory-stackexchange-com-to-the-list-of-site-for-off-topic-questions)

Currently when voting to close a question and choose the "off-topic" as the reason, I am given a list of sites to choose from:

> - belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com
> - belongs on serverfault.com
> - belongs on superuser.com
> - belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com
> - belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

What should I do if I believe the question should go to cstheory? Will it be added to the list?

Comment: This is problematic because people don't always read the FAQ of a site before voting to migrate a question to that site and there are a lot of misunderstandings on SO about what's on-topic on cstheory. If you compare the number of non-research level questions with comments saying "this belongs on cstheory" to the number of questions, which actually do belong on cstheory, you'll probably find that opening up cstheory as a migration path would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a limited number migration paths for any site. If you feel that a question belongs on a site not in the list, flag it for moderator attention. They can migrate questions to any site, if it is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with @sepp2k's comment, there was a [question migrated from Programmers.SE to CSTheory.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/916/migrating-a-question-to-cstheory), which turned-out to be a horrible migration. It's probably a good thing for CSTheory.SE that there isn't a direct path because their community is dedicated to expert-level problems and most users voting to migrate aren't expert enough to understand what an appropriate question is.