# Can we get wordpress.stackexchange.com added to the list of off-topic redirection sites?

Tags: feature-request, wordpress-se

I'm noticing a lot of WordPress questions being asked on Stack Overflow lately. I can't flag these to be moved to wordpress.stackexchange.com because it's not in the list:

[image: Screenshot of the off topic sites list]

Can it be added? Are there any other Stack Exchange sites worth adding?

Comment: What's a lot? What are the numbers you're seeing?

Comment: +! Just recently the volume of WordPress questions has increased on SO.  Some of the questions are relavent here but most could be moved.

Comment: @random I've been looking through the unanswered queue, and I've stumbled across five or six of these in the last day. I suppose I could use the data dump to find all of them, but I'm not that invested.

Comment: Which one of the 5 choices would you remove, in order to add Wordpress to the list?

Comment: @Cody Gray I'd speculate that all five receive more redirections than WordPress would. I'm not proposing we remove one, I'm proposing that the SO team adds a sixth option.

Comment: Fair enough. The problem is that Jeff has said numerous times ([see here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1595/add-a-migration-path-to-pro-web-masters-from-super-user/1704#1704), for example) that there is a maximum of 5 possible migration paths, per site. So you're going to have to make a convincing case to add a sixth option. And once you do so, you have the problem of why should this sixth option be Wordpress, instead of Unix/Linux, Ask Different, Ubuntu, Web Apps, CS Theory, etc. etc.

Comment: The official line has been that you should just flag these posts for ♦ moderator attention. See [Jeff's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77074/add-cstheory-stackexchange-com-to-the-list-of-site-for-off-topic-questions/77078#77078). (Note that I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't necessarily *agree* with it or endorse it.)

Comment: @Brian We ([Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)) just tried to get a sixth option added a couple weeks ago; we're one of the highest migration counts that doesn't have a path from SO. We were told it's very unlikely to happen; they like the count at 5

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks for pointing that out. Jeff's rationale seems to make sense. The list of sites for redirection would get unmanageable eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unlikely we can replace one of the five existing migration paths, but most of the WordPress-related questions will have the [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag, which makes it an ideal example for my proposal to [add migration paths based on the question tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags).

Comment: ... or add a search box like mods have to use to migrate to any SE site that can find only currently appropriate migration paths.