# Could StackOverflow add a "Vote to Migrate" button on Questions?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get wordpress.stackexchange.com added to the list of off-topic redirection sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88951/can-we-get-wordpress-stackexchange-com-added-to-the-list-of-off-topic-redirectio)
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

I think a commonly expressed frustration with the StackExchange network (and StackOverflow in particular) seems to be that one is never quite sure where to Ask -- or Answer -- questions on a particular topic, due to the ever-expanding list of SX sites with narrower topics.

Couldn't you guys (StackExchange) add a new button/link/whatever on the Question page on StackOverflow (and maybe ALL SX sites) that says something like "Recommend Migration to another S.X. site?" and maybe an autocomplete list of available sites?

I think this would really encourage the community to work on organizing Questions into their proper place.

**An Example:**

For users who are heavily involved with, say, WordPress, there's a pretty active StackOverflow community and a widely used WordPress tag. By posting on StackOverflow, I know my question is going to get a lot of exposure. On the other hand, I know I *should* post and answer WordPress questions on the WordPress Answers site (Wordpress.Stackexchange.com), but its not necessarily as widely known, and while the exposure I get there may be more focused and dedicated, I may not necessarily get as MUCH of it.

But if it were easy to "recommend" migration of WordPress Q&A's on S.O. to WordPress Answers -- and perhaps the move is automatic after a certain number of votes -- I think more questions would find their way over there, and over time I think the balance would shift toward the site with the narrower focus.

Comment: This is already part of closing questions as off-topic

Comment: @Jim - no it is not as there is no way to say migrate to Wordpress

Comment: @Mark: Only moderators can migrate to sites other than those listed. Just flag it.

Comment: @Jim: The reasons why there is only a short list of targets in the migration list has been covered before and requests to expand it have been declined.

Comment: *Related:* [More options when flagging for migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration), [Can we get wordpress.stackexchange.com added to the list of off-topic redirection sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88951/can-we-get-wordpress-stackexchange-com-added-to-the-list-of-off-topic-redirectio)

Comment: Wow, -6? You people are brutal.

Answer (score 4):

Not needed.

First of all, the "Off Topic" close reason already offers a (limited) number of sites to migrate to. (The most popular destinations for off-topic questions, as it were.) You also see this list if you flag a question as "it doesn't belong here" and choose "Off topic" (for those who don't have enough reputation to close).

Moderators can already migrate to any site in the network.

As well, if it's a question of "publicity"—making people aware of a site that may cover the topic better, that's a good use for tag wikis. See [android](/questions/tagged/android), for instance.

Besides, just because a question is on-topic elsewhere does not *necessarily* mean it is off-topic here.

In the end, though, the vast majority of the time questions that are posted in the wrong place are pretty bad questions and shouldn't be migrated anyway.

And, don't forget, people don't read. They don't read the FAQ, the don't read the tag wikis, they don't read the message that are put in their way that they have to click through to post. What makes you think they're going to read *yet another message*?

Comment: make it so you can only migrate to a site if you have a certain reputation on that site

Comment: @Mark: That has been suggested, too.

Comment: @Mark: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/require-minimum-reputation-on-the-target-site-for-migration