# Flag question as belonging to the WordPress Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, migration, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get wordpress.stackexchange.com added to the list of off-topic redirection sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88951/can-we-get-wordpress-stackexchange-com-added-to-the-list-of-off-topic-redirectio)

Is there a way to flag questions as belonging to the WordPress stack-exchange?  I see options for the Tex, Server-Fault, along with several other but there upward of 100 Stack Exchange sites now, how to flag others beyond the very limited list?

Comment: @gnat That doesn't really answer the question though, does it? I think the "feature-request" tag here is simply poorly chosen.

Comment: @Bart duplicate feature request if you wish is likely this one: **[Migrate shortlist based on tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68022/165773)** "...if a question is tagged with [tag:wordpress], it is likely that the WordPress SE site would be a good destination"

Answer (score 1):

Leave a custom flag message stating that it might be better off being migrated to that particular SE. Don't do that for old questions though, and perhaps only if it really doesn't fit on SO.